# numpy - efficiently copy values from matrix to matrix using some precalculated map

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, optimization

I have an input matrix A of size I*J

And an output matrix B of size N*M

And some precalculated map of size N*M*2 that dictates for each coordinate in B, which coordinate in A to take. The map has no specific rule or linearity that I can use. Just a map that seems random.

The matrices are pretty big (~5000*~3000) so creating a mapping matrix is out of the question (5000*3000*5000*3000)

I managed to do it using a simple map and loop:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]
```

And I managed to do it using indexing:

```
B[coords_y, coords_x] = A[some_mapping[:, 0], some_mapping[:, 1]]
# Where coords_x, coords_y are defined as all of the coordinates:
# [[0,0],[0,1]..[0,M-1],[1,0],[1,1]...[N-1,M-1]]
```

This works much better, but still kind of slow.

I have infinite time in advance to calculate the mapping or any other utility calculation. But after these precalculations, this mapping should happen as fast as possible.

Currently, the only other option that I see is just to reimplement this in C or something faster...

(Just to make it clear if someone is curious, I'm creating an image out of some other, differently shaped and oriented image with some encoding. But its' mapping is very complicated and not something simple or linear that can be used)

Comment: Did you try : `B = A[mapping[:,:, 0], mapping[:,:,1]]`?

Comment: How can I choose the output shape of this calculation?

Comment: Won't that be automatically done since `mapping` and `B` would be have the same shapes along their first two axes? FYI : I am following your code : `B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]`.

Comment: You are right. It worked and gave me almost 50% improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have infinity time for precomputing you can get a slight speedup by going to flat indexing:

```
map_f = np.ravel_multi_index((*np.moveaxis(mapping, 2, 0),), A.shape)
```

Then simply do:

```
A.ravel()[map_f]
```

Please note that this speedup is on top of the large speedup we get from fancy indexing. For example:

```
>>> A = np.random.random((5000, 3000))
>>> mapping = np.random.randint(0, 15000, (5000, 3000, 2)) % [5000, 3000]
>>> 
>>> map_f = np.ravel_multi_index((*np.moveaxis(mapping, 2, 0),), A.shape)
>>> 
>>> np.all(A.ravel()[map_f] == A[mapping[..., 0], mapping[..., 1]])
True
>>> 
>>> timeit('A[mapping[:, :, 0], mappping[:, :, 1]]', globals=globals(), number=10)
4.101239089999581
>>> timeit('A.ravel()[map_f]', globals=globals(), number=10)
2.7831342950012186
```

If we were to compare to the original loopy code, the speedup would be more like ~40x.

Finally, note that this solution does not only avoid the additional dependency and potential installation nightmare that is numba, but is also simpler, shorter and faster:

```
numba:
precomp:    132.957 ms
main        238.359 ms

flat indexing:
precomp:     76.223 ms
main:       219.910 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def fast(A, B, mapping):
    N, M = B.shape
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]
    return B

from timeit import timeit

A = np.random.random((5000, 3000))
mapping = np.random.randint(0, 15000, (5000, 3000, 2)) % [5000, 3000]

a = np.random.random((5, 3))
m = np.random.randint(0, 15, (5, 3, 2)) % [5, 3]

print('numba:')
print(f"precomp: {timeit('b = fast(a, np.empty_like(a), m)', globals=globals(), number=1)*1000:10.3f} ms")
print(f"main     {timeit('B = fast(A, np.empty_like(A), mapping)', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")

print('\nflat indexing:')
print(f"precomp: {timeit('map_f = np.ravel_multi_index((*np.moveaxis(mapping, 2, 0),), A.shape)', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")
map_f = np.ravel_multi_index((*np.moveaxis(mapping, 2, 0),), A.shape)
print(f"main:    {timeit('B = A.ravel()[map_f]', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")
```

Answer (score 2):

One very nice solution to these types of performance critical problems is to keep it simple and utilize one of the high performance packages. The easiest might be [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) which provides the `jit` decorator that compiles array and loop heavy code to optimized LLVM. Below is a full example:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# Function doing the computation
def normal(A, B, mapping):
    N, M = B.shape
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]
    return B

# The same exact function, but with the Numba jit decorator
@jit
def fast(A, B, mapping):
    N, M = B.shape
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]
    return B

# Create sample data
def create_sample_data(I, J, N, M):
    A = np.random.random((I, J))
    B = np.empty((N, M))
    mapping = np.asarray(np.stack((
        np.random.random((N, M))*I,
        np.random.random((N, M))*J,
        ), axis=2), dtype=int)
    return A, B, mapping
A, B, mapping = create_sample_data(500, 600, 700, 800)

# Run normally
t0 = time()
B = normal(A, B, mapping)
t1 = time()
print('normal took', t1 - t0, 'seconds')

# Run using Numba.
# First we should run the function with smaller arrays,
# just to compile the code.
fast(*create_sample_data(5, 6, 7, 8))
# Now, run with real data
t0 = time()
B = fast(A, B, mapping)
t1 = time()
print('fast took', t1 - t0, 'seconds')
```

This uses your own looping solution, which is inherently slow using standard Python, but as fast as C when using Numba. On my machine the `normal` function executes in 0.270 seconds, while the `fast` function executes in 0.00248 seconds. That is, Numba gives us a **109x speedup** (!) pretty much for free.

Note that the `fast` Numba function is called twice, first with small input arrays and only then with the real data. This is a critical step which is often neglected. Without it, you will find that the performance increase is not nearly as good, as the first call is used to compile the code. The types and dimensions of the input arrays should be the same in this initial call, but the size in each dimension is not important.

I create `B` outside of the function(s) and passed it as an argument (to be "filled with values"). You might just as well allocate `B` inside of the function, Numba does not care.

The easiest way to get Numba is properly via the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) distribution.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/), which can often provide substantial improvements in this kind of simple algorithmic code.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

I, J = 5000, 5000
N, M = 3000, 3000

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, [I, J])
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, [N, M])
mapping = np.dstack([np.random.randint(0, I - 1, (N, M)),
                     np.random.randint(0, J - 1, (N, M))])

B0 = B.copy()

def orig(A, B, mapping):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]

new = njit(orig)
```

which gives us matching results:

```
In [313]: Bold = B0.copy()

In [314]: orig(A, Bold, mapping)

In [315]: Bnew = B0.copy()

In [316]: new(A, Bnew, mapping)

In [317]: (Bold == Bnew).all()
Out[317]: True
```

and is much faster:

```
In [320]: %time orig(A, B0.copy(), mapping)
Wall time: 6.11 s

In [321]: %time new(A, B0.copy(), mapping)
Wall time: 257 ms
```

and faster still after the first call, when it has to do its jit work:

```
In [322]: %time new(A, B0.copy(), mapping)
Wall time: 171 ms

In [323]: %time new(A, B0.copy(), mapping)
Wall time: 163 ms
```

for a 30x improvement for adding two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward optimization you can do is drop the native python loops and use fancy numpy indexing. You already have the array to do that:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(2000,3000)
B = np.empty((2500,3500)) # just for shape, really

# this is the same as your original, but with random indices
mapping = np.stack([np.random.randint(0, A.shape[0] - 1, B.shape),
                    np.random.randint(0, A.shape[1] - 1, B.shape)],
                   axis=-1)

# your loopy original
def loopy(A, B, mapping):
    B = B.copy()
    for i in range(B.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B.shape[1]):
            B[i, j] = A[mapping[i, j, 0], mapping[i, j, 1]]
    return B

# vectorization with fancy indexing
def fancy(A, mapping):
    return A[mapping[...,0], mapping[...,1]]
```

Note that the `fancy` advanced-indexing function doesn't need preallocation of a `B` array, as a new array is constructed by the indexing operation.

There's a slight variation of the fancy indexing version which *could* be marginally more efficient: put your last dimension of `mapping` first, in this way both indexing arrays are contiguous blocks of memory. It turns out from my timing test that this happens to be slower in the above setup. Anyway:

```
mapping_T = mapping.transpose(2, 0, 1).copy() # but it's actually `mapping` without axis=-1 kwarg
# has shape (2, N, M)

def fancy_T(A, mapping_T):
    return A[tuple(mapping_T)]
```

As [Paul Panzer noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234097/numpy-efficiently-copy-values-from-matrix-to-matrix-using-some-precalculated-m/52465269#comment91872752_52465269), just calling `.transpose` on `mapping` will not create a copy, but rather implement the transpose using stride tricks. In order to end up with a contiguous array (which is the point of the optimization) we need to force the creation of a copy.

I get the following timings in ipython:

```
# loopy(A, B, mapping)
6.63 s ± 141 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# fancy(A, mapping)
250 ms ± 3.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# fancy_T(A, mapping_T)
277 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

To be honest I don't understand why the original array order is faster compared to the transposed, but there's that.

Comment: As the numpy transpose is lazy `mapping_T` will _not_ give you contiguous index arrays, check out `mapping_T[0].flags`. You'd have to force a contiguous copy for that.

Comment: @PaulPanzer thank you, I keep forgetting about some of the tricks that numpy does to avoid a copy. Interestingly doing it right makes it _slower_. I can't figure out right now why this happens, even if I define separate copies of subarrays and use `A[mapping1, mapping2]` it seems slower.

Comment: Beats me. Maybe it's because the indices which need to be processed together are next to each other in memory? Just a wild guess.